# How do I set up SSL on kafka with the default truststore?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka

I have inherited a kafka cluster and am getting SSL errors which I need to fix. The settings for the keystore are below (we are deploying a Docker container through Ansible so that's why the settings names aren't the default kafka ones). Our certificate is signed by Go Daddy so we need to use the default Java truststore and don't require self-signed certs (which is what most of the tutorials that I've looked at use).

```
KAFKA_LISTENERS: "SSL://0.0.0.0:9092"
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "SSL://{{ db_host }}:9092"
KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: SSL
KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION: "/kafka/ssl/{{ keystore_name }}"
KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: "{{ keystore_password }}"
KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD: "{{ key_password }}"
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
[2017-03-31 15:04:45,683] WARN Failed to send SSL Close message (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.flush(SslTransportLayer.java:195)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.close(SslTransportLayer.java:163)
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.closeAll(Utils.java:690)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.close(KafkaChannel.java:47)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.close(Selector.java:471)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:348)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:283)
at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:472)
at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:412)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong? Do I need to explicitly tell kafka to use the default truststore?

Thanks!